# Implement a generic C++/CLI interface in a C# generic interface

Tags: c#, interface, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI generic interface like this :

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
namespace Test
{
    generic <class T>
    public interface class IElementList
    {
         property List<T>^ Elements;
    };
}
```

and I want to implement it in a C# generic interface like this :

```
using Test;
namespace U
{
    public interface IElementLightList<T> : IElementList<T>
        where T : IElementLight
    {
        bool isFrozen();
        bool isPastable();
    }
}
```

This don't work, Visual Studio is not able to see C++/CLI IElementList interface !
I tested with a not generic C++/CLI interface and this work.

What I missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a property without any accessor methods.  You'll at a minimum need a getter:

```
generic <class T>
    public interface class IElementList {
        property List<T>^ Elements {
            List<T>^ get();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but this don't solve my problem. In C#, if I try to inherit from a not generic interface, this works, but if I make it generic, this fails, C# is blind in that case.

Comment: I tested this before posting, using the C# code you posted.  Worked fine.  No idea what "fails" or "blind" could possibly mean.  Quite sure however that this answer removes your essential obstacle.  Ask another question to document your new problem properly.

Comment: I found the problem, nothing wrong about this code. Many thanks, your answer led me to the real problem : It was just a missing #include, ILSpy helped me to found it !